# Type amalgamation

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

**Definition**  Let $\mathscr{L}$ be a first-order language and let $\mathcal{K}$ be a class of (possibly finite) $\mathscr{L}$-structures. $\mathcal{K}$ is said to have **amalgamation property** (AP) if for every $A,B_1,B_2\in \mathcal{K}$ and every $\mathscr{L}$-embeddings $f_1:A\rightarrow B_1$ and $f_2:A\rightarrow B_2$ there are an $\mathscr{L}$-structure $C\in\mathcal{K}$ and $\mathscr{L}$-embeddings $f_1^*:B_1\rightarrow C$ and $f_2^*:B_2\rightarrow C$ such that $f_1^*(f_1(a))=f_2^*(f_2(a))$ for all $a\in A$.

I saw the phrase “type amalgamation” in [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bca8/0e77b0a43e3a4917c970b4254ea1db0df0eb.pdf) thesis so my first question is:

**Question (1)** What does type amalgamation mean?

**Definition** A complete first-order theory $T$ is said to be simple  if each type does not fork over some subset $A$ of its domain where $|A|\leq |T|$.

Also in the mentioned thesis the author talks about types amalgamation in simple theories which does not make sense for me. So my second question is:

**Question (2)** What does type amalgamation mean in the context of simple theories? and what are its properties?

Comment: This question would be much better if you provided a reference where you have seen the phrase "type amalgamation" in the context of simple theories. ("Type amalgamation" makes sense to me, but it can mean several different things. I have never heard the phrase "amalgamation over types". Did you mean "amalgamation of types"...?)

Comment: @AlexKruckman I corrected my question.

Comment: Type amalgamation is defined on p. 11 (Definition 1.1.7) of the linked thesis. There, it is a synonym for what is often called the "independence theorem".